# Displaying components depending on available space ANGULAR/CSS

Tags: html, css, angular

## Problem

I need to dynamically display items like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0snz.png) using `*ngFor` directive.

## Description

Each component has the same width, but I can't properly display the vertical alignment (as you can see from the image, the components are "pushed" to top ).

## What I tried

1. I first tried using bootstrap `container`, `row` and `col`
2. I tried using `container` with `display: flex` but no success.

This is the best I've obtained so far

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.fixedWidth {
  margin: 2vw;
  width: 18rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 9px 14px 20px -7px rgba(224, 224, 224, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 9px 14px 20px -7px rgba(224, 224, 224, 1);
  box-shadow: 9px 14px 20px -7px rgba(224, 224, 224, 1);
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="text-center center fixedWidth" *ngFor="let collect of collections">
    <app-user-collection [collection]="collect">
    </app-user-collection>

  </div>
</div>
```

## Question

How can I achieve [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0snz.png) using angular, bootstrap, or CSS?

## EDIT

Thank you for answering!

Here is [what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vATkh.png) and [what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlWB9.png). The collection's order is not important!

This is the main container

```css
.categoriesHeight {
    height: 100vh;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .categoriesHeight {
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-1 categoriesHeight">
      <app-user-menu></app-user-menu>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-11 vh-100">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Here's the `app-user-collection`

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-12">
    <p><strong>
      {{ collection.name }}
    </strong></p>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="row" *ngFor="let pack of collection.packets">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <app-collection-packets [packet]="pack">
    </app-collection-packets>
  </div>
</div>
```

And `app-collection-packets`

```html
<p>
  {{ packet.name }}
</p>
```

Comment: Can't understand what is your goal. Can you make an image too ?

Comment: What you want to achieve is called "masonry layout". I've already done it inside a website, and had to manually generate 3 lists (one per column). Then to feed each list, you have to loop on your items, gather the exact height of each item (which is the hard part if it is not as simple as an image), and then add the item in the smallest column. This is not so easy and depends much on your case, so my advice is to read more about "masonry layout"

Comment: @Random thank you very much, I'm going to read and learn about this layout. Sorry about my bad English btw!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a template but with this you'll have to compromise with the order of collections i.e. instead of going from left to right they'll run top to bottom. And I hope you are using bootstrap 4.
I hope this will give you enough to implement it in your project structure.

```
<div class="container d-flex">

  <div class="d-block mr-2">
    <div class="border d-flex flex-column p-5 mb-2">
      <p>test1</p>
      <p>test1</p>
      <p>test1</p>
      <p>test1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="border d-flex flex-column p-5 mb-2">
      <p>test1</p>
      <p>test1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="border d-flex flex-column p-5 mb-2">
      <p>test1</p>
      <p>test1</p>
      <p>test1</p>
      <p>test1</p>
      <p>test1</p>
      <p>test1</p>
      <p>test1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-block mr-2">
    <div class="border d-flex flex-column p-5 mb-2">
      <p>test2</p>
      <p>test2</p>
      <p>test2</p>
      <p>test2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="border d-flex flex-column p-5 mb-2">
      <p>test2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="border d-flex flex-column p-5 mb-2">
      <p>test2</p>
      <p>test2</p>
      <p>test2</p>
      <p>test2</p>
      <p>test2</p>
      <p>test2</p>
      <p>test2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-block">
    <div class="col border d-flex flex-column p-5 mb-2">
      <p>test3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="border d-flex flex-column p-5 mb-2">
      <p>test3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="border d-flex flex-column p-5 mb-2">
      <p>test3</p>
      <p>test3</p>
      <p>test3</p>
      <p>test3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="border d-flex flex-column p-5 mb-2">
      <p>test3</p>
      <p>test3</p>
      <p>test3</p>
      <p>test3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="border d-flex flex-column p-5 mb-2">
      <p>test3</p>
      <p>test3</p>
      <p>test3</p>
      <p>test3</p>
      <p>test3</p>
      <p>test3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yqx2zwd9/1/

Comment: the problem is that using flex, all items will be aligned "by row". So if an item has half height of a row, an item in the 2nd row will never come near the 1st row, there will be a space between the item of the first row, and the item of the 2nd row.